# Java glfwSetScrollCallback, do to 'cbfun' for Memory Leaks?

Tags: java, callback, user-input, lwjgl, glfw

I was just curious ... when using `glfwSetScrollCallback(window, scrollfun)` in java, GLFW 3.2, do I need to release/remove the callback at anytime, as in, `glfwSetScrollCallback(window, null)`? Will it cause memory leaks or increased usage if I do not?

I just want to make sure that I am using it without causing too much additional strain. I do understand that I can use this to disable getting the callback at certain times, which is nice, and kind of handy to multi game builds, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing on the GLFW side that may cause any memory leaks for non-released window callbacks, such as the scroll callback, because GLFW itself does not *own* that memory. It is just a function pointer kept in a per-window variable (that exists anyways - otherwise it is `NULL`).

From the LWJGL side, which owns the memory for the callback object, instantiating the callback class to an object implementing the callback Java interface does require both JVM on-heap as well as off-heap memory.

When you instantiate the callback object (e.g. `org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWScrollCallback`), then you *must* also call its `free()` methode (inherited from `org.lwjgl.system.NativeResource`) in order to dispose of the allocated native memory (LWJGL 3 does not use the `finalize()` mechanism). Currently, LWJGL 3 uses the `dyncall` library to generate native executable code for generated callback functions.

So: You can register and unregister a single instantiated callback object on a GLFW window as many times as you like, without any issues. Just make sure that you do it in a thread-safe manner by only calling window-related functions on the main thread. See the GLFW functions' documentation for that.